# How to get a unique Android device identificator in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, identifier, hardware-id

For my app we need a unique device id, to detect which devices was already assigned (used) to customer and which is not assigned (clean) and ready to assign

The problem is Android 10 and above restrict access to hardware device number, IMEI, mac-adress.

> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device.
> The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.
> I tried to use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) but it generates a different key after every app reinstall. If you have any solution, ideas, please fell free to suggest

Comment: There is an extensive question over the history of Android about [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2785485/295004). But why track the device when you should track the user (i.e. allow only one or only a few login devices, enforced server side). If you need to track business/company owned devices then [Mobile Device Management/Enterprise Mobility Management](https://www.android.com/enterprise/) is what your business should be looking at.

Comment: @MorrisonChang devices are delivered with pre-installed app, and we need to detect the same device when user reinstall the app

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib: device_information 0.0.4
It's old but it works for me :)

Comment: This lib don't show unique Id and throws an exception when trying to receive IMEI